# For a bivariate normal distribution, what's the probability that X < Y?

Tags: statistics

You have two normal distributions. In the problem I'm studying they're independent, but I'm not sure that matters. The question is what is the probability that X < Y?

So far I've been able to set up the integral and do a numerical integration to get an answer, but I wonder if there's a more analytical way? Here's what my integration looks like:

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_y}e^{-
\frac{1}{2}(\frac{y-\mu_y}{\sigma_y})^2}dy \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_x}e^{-
\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu_x}{\sigma_x})^2}dx $

So the first integral is the CDF of y up to x, and it's being multiplied by the pdf of x.

I know I can't integrate this directly, but it feels like there should be some way to continue the analytical approach, even if it does require looking at normal distribution tables in the end?

Comment: Hint: $P(X < Y) = P(X - Y < 0).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider the variable $W:=X-Y$. You want $P(W<0)$. Notice that $W$ has a normal distribution since $X$ and $Y$ are independent normal. What are $E(W)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(W)$?

Comment: Hm, ok, so $E(W) = E(X) - E(Y)$ and $Var(W) = Var(X) + Var(Y)$, not in general but true in this case given the coefficients of 1 for X and -1 for Y. So I would need to apply a Z transformation such that $P(W < 0) = P(\frac{W-\mu}{\sigma} < \frac{-\mu}{\sigma}) = P(Z < \frac{-\mu}{\sigma})$ is that right?

Comment: Looks like that worked, I had an issue when checking the results between $\sigma$ and $\sigma^2$ but after resolving that everything works out as expected, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This probability function can be expressed without integrals. Let $r=\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$, $\theta = \arctan(v/u)$.

$\int \int e^{-\frac{1}{2}u^2  } du e^{-\frac{1}{2}v^2  }dv =\int \int e^{-\frac{1}{2}(u^2+v^2)  } dudv = \int \int r e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2  } dr d\theta = -\theta e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2} $

so

$\int \int e^{-\frac{1}{2}u^2  } du e^{-\frac{1}{2}v^2  }dv= - \arctan(v/u) e^{-\frac{1}{2} (u^2+v^2)}$

I omitted a constant of course. Make sure to write the correct constants and scaling factors everywhere as well since I ignored them. They don't affect the process of integration.

This is keeping in mind that you do the u-substitutions $u = \frac{x-\mu_x}{\sigma_x}$ and $v= \frac{y-\mu_y}{\sigma_y}$. It's also possible to consider other assignments for $\theta$ to account for other quadrants in the plane or when $y=\mu_y$.

Now that all that needs to be done is to follow the typical procedure for explicit integration. Try using the range $[a,\infty)$ for $y$ and $(-\infty, a]$ for $x$. At minimum, this gives $x\leq y$ which is the same probability as $x<y$.